# C# Index out of range - Array without content

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, range

Hello Stackoverflow people!

I'm making a school project and currently got the whole program working, but I want to make it fail proof, but I'm having trouble that an array goes out of range if I just press ENTER instead of putting any info in.

```
string[] strIpAddress = ipAndSubnetArray[0].Split('.');
        string[] strSubnetMask = new string[] { "" };
        int[] intSubnetMask = new int[] { };
        string strCIDR = "";
        string cidrSubnetmask = "";

        if (ipAndSubnetArray[1].Length > 2)
        {
            strSubnetMask = ipAndSubnetArray[1].Split('.');
            intSubnetMask = strArray2IntArray(strSubnetMask);
        }
        else if (ipAndSubnetArray[1].Length < 3)
        {
            strCIDR = Convert.ToString(ipAndSubnetArray[1]);
            cidrSubnetmask = cidrTilDeci(Convert.ToInt32(strCIDR));
            strSubnetMask = cidrSubnetmask.Split('.');
            intSubnetMask = strArray2IntArray(strSubnetMask);
        }
        else if (ipAndSubnetArray == null)
        {
            Main();
        }
```

I tried fixing with with ipAndSubnetArray == null but that didn't seem to do the trick. Any suggestions? If you need more of the code let me know.

Comment: Check for null or a 0 length FIRST

Comment: What they said ^^

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code an see why it fails?

Comment: Also, if this part of code is on the function "Main" and someone gets bored and holds the return key you will have an `StackOverflow` exception,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming data comes in from a terminal or other input when you press enter and is passed in via `ipAndSubnetArray`. `ipAndSubnetArray` is apparently `null` when this happens. Your check for this is at the end, move it to the top to prevent accessing any indexes that aren't there.

The `ipAndSubnetArray.Length >= 2` check is to guarantee you can access `ipAndSubnetArray[1]`. You could also do this inside like so `if (ipAndSubnetArray.Length > 1 && ipAndSubnetArray[1].Length > 2)`.

```
if(ipAndSubnetArray != null && ipAndSubnetArray.Length >= 2) {
    string[] strIpAddress = ipAndSubnetArray[0].Split('.');
    string[] strSubnetMask = new string[] { "" };
    int[] intSubnetMask = new int[] { };
    string strCIDR = "";
    string cidrSubnetmask = "";

    if (ipAndSubnetArray[1].Length > 2)
    {
        strSubnetMask = ipAndSubnetArray[1].Split('.');
        intSubnetMask = strArray2IntArray(strSubnetMask);
    }
    else if (ipAndSubnetArray[1].Length < 3)
    {
        strCIDR = Convert.ToString(ipAndSubnetArray[1]);
        cidrSubnetmask = cidrTilDeci(Convert.ToInt32(strCIDR));
        strSubnetMask = cidrSubnetmask.Split('.');
        intSubnetMask = strArray2IntArray(strSubnetMask);
    }
} else {
    Main()
}
```

Comment: Great. If it works accept the answer so others see the question is answered.